# Magento reindex from command line, still having timeout error

Tags: magento-1.7, php, cli

I'm trying to reindex my catalog_url_rewrite table (Magento website) through the command line using the command "php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url" in /shell. I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /var/www/domain.com/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php on line 141
```

The file and line on the error varies.

I've double checked to confirm that php in the command line is indeed using the php-cli version (by using "php -i") and that there are no limits in its config that should yield such an error.

I've also looked around to see if any magento file is setting the "set_time_limit" manually, but couldn't find anything that points that way. I can't find the 60 seconds max_execution_time anywhere.

Any idea on what's going on?

Edit:

So far I've tried:

- Running "php -d max_execution_time=0 indexer.php --reindex catalog_url"
- Setting "set_time_limit(9000);" on indexer.php directly.
- Running "php -i" to see "Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli" & "Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini"
- Setting max_execution_time on fpm's php.ini to 61 just to see if it was using it by accident.
- Made sure "set_time_limit(60)" is not hardcoded anywhere in the magento framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've run into this. The issue is that shell scripts extending `Mage_Shell_Abstract` inherit behaviour that applies PHP ini settings parsed from Magento's `.htaccess` file.

Take a look at the method `protected function _applyPhpVariables()` in `shell/abstract.php`.

Easiest fix, is to just edit `.htaccess` and comment out the `php_value` directives for `execution_time` and or `memory_limit`. Alternatively you can extend the indexer by overriding the `applyPhpVariables()` method and stop it processing the `.htaccess`.

I made sizeable donations to my swear jar when I first discovered this 'feature'.

Comment: "Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully"

Holy sh** man, what a savior! Such a strange behavior, never would have thought of that. I just commented out the whole function and it worked like a charm. If I'm ever in London I'm making sure to buy you a beer.

Comment: This is good to know and nice work super sleuthing! Now I'm curious why I've never run into this since I've had index jobs that easily run up to 4 hrs after a full-import of 5-million products. Guess I've got some digging to do to satisfy my curiosity. :D

Answer (score 5):

Try running this from the root of Magento installation:

```
php -d max_execution_time=0 ./shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

If this command fails with that same error, then something crazy is going on. :)

Comment: This is nicely done. reindexall is another valid option to be passed.

Comment: Yea someone suggested the same over at stackoverflow, but I still get the same error. There is indeed something crazy going on and I can't figure out what.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what version of PHP do you have? Could you post the output of `php --version`

Comment: Also is this a shared host or a dedicated environment you have full control over?

Comment: PHP 5.3.27-1~dotdeb.0 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul 25 2013 19:30:39)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.14, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH

Comment: And it's a dedicated server with 8 core CPU, 8Gb ram and a SSD disk. It's a good machine.

Comment: This one has got me stumped then… the only case I know of where it wouldn't be honored is an [old bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37306) in PHP 5.1. The CLI SAPI is not supposed to have a time limit, nor even allow limiting via calls to set_time_limit or ini_set etc. Hmm...

Comment: Yea I was stumped too, but check the accepted answer below to see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to point out is that Magento shell commands parse the htaccess file and will apply settings (such as time limit) that it finds. I would check your htaccess file.

See this post I wrote a while ago:
http://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/magento-shell-scripts-and-memory-limit-woes-solution.html