# How can I solve product attribute reindex error: "Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted"?

Tags: magento-1.9, reindex, memory

When i try to reindex, I got error like this:

[image]

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10095/magento-reindex-from-command-line-still-having-timeout-error

Comment: @Manashvibirla the error says it ran out of memory, not a timeout.

Comment: if you have any idea @ SR_Magento

Comment: I am certain it is a php memory limit. How much memory does your server have?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of your memory in your `.htaccess`

```
php_value memory_limit = 64
```

to

```
 php_value memory_limit = XXX
```

XXX = Memory allocated

Depending on how much memory you have, you should set it to 256MB or more:

[Recommended Magento PHP memory limit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13050/recommended-magento-php-memory-limit)

Comment: Not working ...

Comment: @JeevaRathinam, Check if your hosting provider allows increasing memory via htaccess first. Most shared hosting providers don't.